# dict.setdefault(key, []).append() --> get rid of additional list

Tags: python, dictionary

How can i prevent from adding a list into a list when using setdefault with a list type definition.

```
output = dict()
output.setdefault("key", []).append(["name", 1])
print output
>>> {'key': [['name', 1]]}
```

Desired output

```
>>> {'key': ['name', 1]}
```

Comment: What should happen if the key is already present?

Comment: If the key is already present, `extend()` extends _the existing list_ for that key.  You can try it by yourself, by duplicating `….setdefault(…).extend(…)`.

Comment: @EOL: Yes, and that behavior may not be what's desired. I know I certainly wouldn't want to work with values of the form `['name', 2, 'name', 1, 'name', 3]`. I suspect that either the values really should be nested lists, or the code should do `output['key'] = ['name', 1]` instead of using `setdefault` at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `.extend` rather than `.append` - the former adds a list of items to a list, the latter adds a single item - so if you pass it a list, it adds the list as a single subitem.

Comment: It's ok to extend an empty list: `output.setdefault("key", []).extend(["name", 1])`

Comment: @user1767754 extend doesn't require any elements. It works on an empty list. In fact, the code from your question works just fine if you change `append` to `extend` and nothing else.

Comment: Ohhhh....that works! I tried it accidently with just adding an element, but it expect a list.... my bad.

Comment: Explicitly: `my_list = []; my_list.extend([1, 2, 3]); print my_list` gives `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @user1767754 You can learn more about `extend` and `append` in this SO question [Python - append vs. extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)